# como calcular las horas entre fechas en postgresql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Necesito calcular las horas entre dos fechas, pero solo necesito que me calcule cuantas horas pasaron en un rango especifico, el cual seria de 8:00 hrs a 18:00 hrs.

He visto este código que creo que puede funcionar pero no se como restringir para que solo me cuente las horas en ese intervalo.

He probado con esto:

`SELECT DATE_PART('day', '2011-12-30 08:55'::timestamp - '2011-12-30 09:05'::timestamp) * 24 +  DATE_PART('hour', '2011-12-30 08:55'::timestamp - '2011-12-30 09:05'::timestamp);`

Esta se supone que me daría cuantas horas han pasado de las 8:55 a las 9:05, pero me arroja 0.

Soy novato en esto de base de datos, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para el calculo se puede convertir las horas a segundos y calcular la diferencia. El valor resultante se puede dividir por 3600 para obtener le valor en horas (decimal).

```
SELECT ( EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2011-12-30 09:05:00')-EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2011-12-30 08:55:00')) / 3600 as hours;
```

Se puede convertir de segundos a formato de hora (HH:MI:SS) usando:

```
SELECT to_char ((600 ||' seconds')::interval, 'HH24:MI:SS' ) as time1;
```

**Nota para MySQL**

Para MYSQL, calcular existe `TIME_TO_SEC()` para convertir a segundos, luego con `SEC_TO_TIME()` puedes convertir al formato `HH:MM:SS`

Ejemplos:

```
SELECT time_to_sec('2011-12-30 09:05:00')-time_to_sec('2011-12-30 08:55:00')
```

Retornará `600` (segundos).

Ahora con `sec_to_time()`

```
sec_to_time(time_to_sec('2011-12-30 09:05:00')-time_to_sec('2011-12-30 08:55:00'))
```

Retornará `00:10:00` (10 minutos)

Si solo te interesa saber el valor en horas (decimal), divides los segundos por `3600` y te dara, en este caso (`0.16666666` horas)

Comment: Muchas gracias, aunque en concreto no use la función que muestras ya que esta creo que no existe en postgresql, fue lo que hizo que se me prendiera la ampolleta y comenze a buscar como pasar las fechas a segundos y al final pude encontrar la solucion que es similar a la funcion que pones. Gracias!!!

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, agregue la info para postgresql